# Why is an electron in a radioactive decay indicated with a '-1' where the atomic number should be

Tags: electrons, radiation, radioactivity

I'm just a high school student so this may seem dumb but none of my teachers nor my seniors could clarify this.

In the balanced equations of any radioactive decay every atom is represented as $$^x_yZ$$

Wherever an electronic is emitted the 'x' position is indicated by -1 and thus the atomic numbers balance.

But it never made sense to me why. I even tried googling but couldn't find what I needed.

Below is one such reaction for an example:$$^{228}_{88}Ra {\longrightarrow}^{228}_{89}Ac+ 
^0_{-1}e$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number at the bottom left is the charge (measured in multiples of the elementary charge). For  a nucleus this charge is equal to the number of protons ( each having charge $+1$) or the atomic number. For an electron the charge is just $-1$.

Comment: Oh so $^{228}_{88}Ra$ is only referring to the radium nucleus and not the atom itself?

Comment: @VamsiKrisha Yes, correct. The given reaction is a nuclear reaction. The other electrons swirling around the nucleus are not involved in this reaction.